# Which Query to use in Elasticsearch tp perform all substring matched results?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I want to implement a shop name search feature, now if i write a shop name "nite out" then I want my results containing all sub string "nite" and "out" and "nite out" also.

I tried using prefix query but wasn't able to perform that. I have heard about fuzzy query but don't know will it solve my problem or not.

Can anyone please tell me which ES query should i use to get "nite out" matched results at the top and rest "nite" and "out" results also but below "nite out" matched results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that you have your data already indexed such that `nite`, `out` and `nite out` are the tokens matching whatever documents.

One of the ways to do this would be to use would be the [Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html). The Match query uses an analyzer to get that `fuzziness` that you are looking for. In this specific case, we could use the the whitespace analyzer to get the results you are looking for. It will look at the query `nite out` and split it into `nite` and `out`. The match query will then search for those two tokens, and score based on relevance. A document with `nite out` analyzed as both `nite` and `out` will have a higher score than a document with just `nite` or `out` by themselves.

Here is a three document example, using dynamic mapping:

Index our docs:

```
PUI   {"value":"out"}
PUT   {"value":"nite"}
PUT   {"value":"nite out"}
```

Now construct the query:

```
GET _search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "value": {
            "query": "nite out",
            "analyzer": "whitespace"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

We don't actually need to specify the whitespace analyzer here, in fact we can just remove that line (and the preceding comma) altogether. The match query will run the query text over the analyzer used by the field we are querying at index time. In our case it is the standard analyzer, which splits the text up into `nite` and `out`.

The results:

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.2712221,
            "_source": {
               "value": "nite out"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.04500804,
            "_source": {
               "value": "nite"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.04500804,
            "_source": {
               "value": "out"
            }
         }
      ]
```

I would encourage you to read over [this link here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/term-vs-full-text.html) to learn about different search mechanisms in elasticsearch

Comment: can u pls tell me one thing actually i want "nite out" to be searched such that  strings exactly match with "nite" OR "out" as prefix can u please tell me for that what can i use it will be really helpful and really thanks for your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure what you mean. Show some exmaples of what you want matched, and what you don't want matched in your question.

Comment: ok for example if i search "nite out" then answers will be "nite * " where * means anyting or nothing, OR "out *", in short i want my first term before space as exact match and second one as a prefix of any string. i want both answers

Comment: for example all answers wil be "nite", "nite outing", "outing", "out", "nite out"

Comment: do u get it or not ??

Comment: pls have a relook at the comment.

Comment: first it should show "nite out" then "nite outing", "nite" together "out" , "outing"